TYPO3 set Google Analytics tag based on domain with typoscript
I have a multidomain where I'd like to set the individual Google Analytics tag with typoscript setup (TYPO3 V11).
I start with constants.typoscript:
myExt {
  googleAnalytics {
    default = G-SITE1
    site2 = G-SITE2
  }
}

followed by setup.typoscript which works fine:
# google analytics
page.headerData.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.3.value(
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={$myExt.googleAnalytics.default}"></script>
    ...
)

I thought the following should work, but all variants I tried failed:
# Multidomain
config.googleAnalytics = {$myExt.googleAnalytics.default}

[request.getNormalizedParams().getHttpHost() == "site2.com"]
    config.googleAnalytics = {$myExt.googleAnalytics.site2}
[END]

# google analytics
page.headerData.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.3.value(
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={$config.googleAnalytics}"></script>
    ...
)


It sounds a bit like your GoogleIDs should be site-settings... https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/SiteSettings.html

Is the second snippet ("all variants I tried failed") all in your setup.typoscript? Then it cannot work like this. You're setting the TS property config.googleAnalytics, and later you're trying to use it as a TS constant...

@julian-hofmann, it should be site-settings, and the second comment ... I KNOW it does not work, if you know how to prepare the constants, and make a variable the correct GoogleID for the correct domain, please post an answer ... for the time being I worked with the solution Heinz Schilling posted, but the answer is limited to non editable constants

You can set constants values based on root page uid of the different domains.
constants.typoscript
myExt.googleAnalytics = G-SITE1

[tree.rootLine[0]["uid"] == ROOT-PAGE-UID]
    myExt.googleAnalytics = G-SITE2
[END]

setup.typoscript
# google analytics
page.headerData.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.3.value(
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={$myExt.googleAnalytics}"></script>
    ...
)

Docs about condition:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#tree-rootline

@Heinz_Schilling that might work!!, I tried to keep my question simple but the conditional value should be a variable because the multisite has 6 domains and the editor should be able to set the tag, and two of the domains share the same page UID, thanks for the input though
